# Pyramid server stops on first call when run with pydev

Tags: pycharm, pydev, pyramid

I am running pyramid server in pycharm with pydev. On first call through browser server crashes.

Output:
    pydev debugger: process 66372 is connecting

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 141.1116)
Starting server in PID 66372.
serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080

Process finished with exit code 137
```

what could be wrong, where to look for some kind of info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug that was fixed in PyCharm 4.5.1, then resurfaced, then fixed again in 4.5.3.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15007
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14969

Suggest updating to the latest stable release, or if on 5 EAP, report the issue through their bug tracker.

Comment: thanks for nice info. I did workaround by using Python 3 instead of Python 2 which was fine for my project.